# Overloading the stream insertion operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I am making a three-dimensional vector class (called `Vector3`) in c++. Right now, I am trying to overload the stream insertion operator (`<<`) so that I can directly print all of the vector's components all at once. I copied the sintax from [MSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but I get an 3 errors.

> error: passing 'const Vector3 ' as 'this' argument of 'float Vector3::**getX()**' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>   
>   error: passing 'const Vector3 ' as 'this' argument of 'float Vector3::**getY()**' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>   
>   error: passing 'const Vector3 ' as 'this' argument of 'float Vector3::**getZ**()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

<sup>(differences are marked in bold)</sup>

In `Vector3.h` under public, I entered this function declaration:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Vector3 &vector);
```

In `Vector3.cpp`, I implemented it:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector3& vector)
{
    os << "(" << vector.getX() << ", " << vector.getY() << ", " << vector.getZ() << ")" << endl;
    return os;
}
```

It should print out something like `(x, y, z)` according to the x, y, and z variables.

On a side note, shouldn't the `vector.getX()` lines use the `->` instead of the dot, because the vector object is an address pointer?

Comment: Is `getX()` a `const` member function?

Comment: Your `operator<<` doesn't need to be a `friend` if it only calls public member functions of `Vector3`.

Comment: As to your side note, no it should not - the `vector` parameter is not a pointer (syntactically), it is a reference.  Reference variables have the same "dot" syntax as value variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `const` qualifiers to your `get...` functions.

```
class Vector3
{
    public:
        float getX() const {return x;};
};
```

A `const`-qualified function simply means you can call it on a `const` instance of the class. Here, the getters won't change anything. However, if you don't specify that, the compiler doesn't know, so calling a function that might change something on a `const` variable is not allowed.

You can read about `const`-correctness [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html).

And the dot notation is correct, `vector` is not a *pointer*, but a *reference* (i.e. another name for some other `Vector3`. The `&` notation can be a little confusing for beginners I think. Roughly: when you apply it to a variable, it takes its address, when it's part of a type, it means that type is a reference. E.g. see [here](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~patrick/csc418/wi2004/notes/PointersVsRef.pdf) or [here](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/pointers.html).

Comment: Ah I see. What exactly does making a function `const` do? Care to elaborate?

Comment: And what if I need to call the `getX()` in a non `const` instance of the class?

Comment: non-const can always be implicitly cast to const safely in this case, which is to say it'd work just fine

Comment: @DantheMan Making a function const means that its `this` pointer has type `T const*`, rather than `T*`.  It also means that you can call the function on a const instance, or through a pointer or reference to const.  There's no problem calling it through a non-const instance, reference, or pointer, however, since the `T*` which occurs naturally converts implicitly to `T const*`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've not declared your getX, getY, and getZ functions as const.  The compiler won't let you use them because it can't be sure that they do not change the state of the object.

You should be able to change their declarations to the following form:

```
float Vector3::getX() const
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float Vector3::getX()
```

must be changed to

```
float Vector3::getX() const
```